# Google cloud function and android application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to create social networking application whose features will be:

- Authentication
- Send Messages on newsfeed activity(visible to all the authenticated people)
- when somebody comment/likes your message send notification
- Followers
- Followings
- when somebody follows you send notification

Is firebase realtime database enough for this or I have to use firebase cloud function? or AWS dynamoDB or what would be the good combination to achieve desired functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Firebase Cloud Functions** to send notification automatically on **follow**/**comment**/**like**.

All what you need is Firebase.

AWS is pretty much harder to init than Firebase.

[You can see here some samples of using Firebase Cloud Functions.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)

[This sample will help you to send notifications on **follow**/**comment**/**like**.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications)

Comment: Firebase also has services like for authentication, realtime database, push notification(called cloud messaging i guess) individually, how these services are different from cloud function?

Comment: With Cloud Functions you can add triggers on the database to called a function when a follower is added for example and in this function you can send the notification. Of course you have to implement it. The Firebase documentation is pretty clear, you should read it.